# Spreading cost per month over duration of months in Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a tricky problem in Sheets.

I need a formula to calculate running total costs for each month from Nov 2019 on wards (column B).

Currently, my formula for B2 is:

```
=SUMIFS($F$2:$F$6,$E$2:$E$6,">="&A2,$E$2:$E$6,"<="&(EDATE(A2,1)-1))
```

Basically, this finds all values in cells F2:F6 whose dates (in column E) match that of A2.

E.g. Cell B3 is the total cost for December, so cells F3 and F6 are a match (200 + 300 = 500)

**However**, this does not take into account the duration of the cost (column G).

This means that the total cost for December 2019 (cell B3) should actually be 600 (because the November cost duration lasts 12 months). Meaning **there is a cumulative cost for the duration of months the cost lasts for**.

[image: sheets]

I am pretty much stuck on this. If anyone could help that would be great!

Comment: seems to me that instead having columns G and E (cost in initial month?) what you really need is E and another column: one for the initial month and one for the final month. Then you would include the cost per month every time it falls between those 2. The additional column could be calculated based on column G if you like.

Comment: These rows are auto-generated from another system. So this is all I have to work with, I need it fully automated! thanks @TonyM

Comment: Since you can put formulas in column B, can you put formula's in other columns? For example, something like =E1+G1*30 placed into column H will give you the final month (if I'm understanding correctly that E gives the initial month). My suggestion was that you could then modify your formula in B to include items in the summation between the dates in E & H. Or if you don't want to use another column you could do a similar calculation within =SUMIFS so that you capture costs between the active months. Anyway, that makes sense to me...

Answer (score 0):

So as long as the date given in column A intersect between "start date" and "start date" + x months the cost per month should be applied?

So according to this, Jan-2020 will have a cost of 600 in this example:
[image]
`Sant/Falskt = True/False`

Green rows = date intersect between Start and End date

If that is correct then this formula should do the job, paste in B2:
`=SUMPRODUCT((--(A2>=DATE(YEAR($E$2:$E$6),MONTH($E$2:$E$6),1))*--(A2<DATE(YEAR($E$2:$E$6),MONTH($E$2:$E$6)+$G$2:$G$6,DAY($E$2:$E$6))))*$F$2:$F$6)`

Comment: This is almost correct, except your start+dur is adding days instead of months. The output I am getting from B2:B5 is 100, 305, 5, 30, 0. It should be: 100, 305, 105, 135, 135. Thanks